# What is going on with the "return fibonacci... " in this program?

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I have problem understanding what the `return fibonacci( number-1 ) + fibonacci( number-2 )` does in the following program:

```
import sys
def fibonacci( number ):
    if( number <= 2  ):
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci( number-1 ) + fibonacci( number-2 )
```

The problem is that I can't imagine how this line works:

```
return fibonacci( number-1 ) + fibonacci( number-2 )
```

Does the both of the "fibonacci( number-1 )" and "fibonacci( number-2 )" being processed at the same time? or the "fibonacci( number-1 )" is the first to be processed and then the second one?

I only see that processing both of them would eventually return '1' so the last result I expect to see it is a '1 + 1' = '2'

I would appreciate a lot, If someone can elaborately explain the process of its calculation.

I think this is a very newb question but I can't really get a picture of its process.

Comment: Short answer: Python evaluates the first one first, and when complete, it'll evaluate the second call.

Comment: it should be `if number < 2:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
>>> def fibonacci(number):
...     if number < 2:
...         return number
...     print "Number is currently %d, getting fibonacci(%d)" % (number, number - 1)
...     minus_one = fibonacci(number-1)
...     print "Number is currently %d, just got fibonacci(%d), now getting fibonacci(%d)" % (number, number - 1, number - 2)
...     minus_two = fibonacci(number-2)
...     print "Number is currently %d, returning %d + %d" % (number, minus_one, minus_two)
...     return minus_one + minus_two
```

So that when you call `fibonacci` you get something like this:

```
>>> fibonacci(4)
Number is currently 4, getting fibonacci(3)
Number is currently 3, getting fibonacci(2)
Number is currently 2, getting fibonacci(1)
Number is currently 2, just got fibonacci(1), now getting fibonacci(0)
Number is currently 2, returning 1 + 0
Number is currently 3, just got fibonacci(2), now getting fibonacci(1)
Number is currently 3, returning 1 + 1
Number is currently 4, just got fibonacci(3), now getting fibonacci(2)
Number is currently 2, getting fibonacci(1)
Number is currently 2, just got fibonacci(1), now getting fibonacci(0)
Number is currently 2, returning 1 + 0
Number is currently 4, returning 2 + 1
3
```

It's still complex, but at least now you can see what the function is doing to calculate your number.

Comment: right!! thanks a lot this is what I try to understand. And... the thing is I'm not good at debugging or testing, sry, if I do the question would not be posted. thanks again!!

Comment: OP, this is a great way to visualize stuff what you are in doubt, good answer! +1

Comment: err... sry, What does 'OP' means?

Comment: "OP" = "Original Poster" (either of the question or the answer)

Comment: @user1478598 sorry, yes OP means Original Poster, I meant you :)

Answer (score 3):

> Does the both of the "fibonacci( number-1 )" and "fibonacci( number-2 )" being processed at the same time? or the "fibonacci( number-1 )" is the first to be processed and then the second one?

Does it matter?

---

What is happening is that the function is called twice. Once with the value of `number` -1 and once -2, for the value of `number` that was passed in to the *current* "instance" of the function.

Say you call `fibonacci(3)`. That line would end up being:

```
return fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)
```

Comment: And then `fibonacci(2)` is evaluated first, `fibonacci(1)` second.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Fair enough, but for the end result to be understood, it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Read between the lines. The OP is confused about recursion and how two calls to the same function on one line can work. My point is that the mechanism doesn't really matter for understanding how this works. If you change the order of evaluation, you end up with the same understanding.

Comment: I know :-) But there is a possibility he thought the methods were executed in parallel.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Which would still not matter, as the line would only evaluate when both (imaginary) "stacks" would complete...

Comment: So the plus '+' will not be performed until the left side is all evaluated and then the right side? right?

Answer (score 2):

I very much like Nolen Royalty's answer, but it's still a bit hard to visualize. So, after a bit of mucking about:
[image]

... where time flows left-to-right, with minor tweaking to prevent some overlapping edges. Leaf nodes, which do not recurse, are orange.

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble understanding recursion at first, so I'll try to go through the function.

Now lets say you call fibonacci(4)

Since the number is greater that 2 python will go to this line:

return fibonacci( number-1 ) + fibonacci( number-2 )

So it will start evaluating and call:

fibonacci(3) #this is fibonacci(4 - 1)

Since every time it encounters a function call it must run it (so to say).

So now it will try to do fibonacci(3), and since it is greater than 2:

it will go to this line again:

return fibonacci( number-1 ) + fibonacci( number-2 )

Now it was calling it with 3 so when it gets to fibonacci( number-1 ) it will do:

fibonacci(2) #this is fibonacci(3 - 1)

Since the numer is equal to 2, this recursive call will return 1. Now you have to remember/imagine that python knows the answer to fibonacci(2) so to say.

So now that it has an answer for fibonacci(2) it will continue to execute this line:

return fibonacci( number-1 ) + fibonacci( number-2 )

Specifically this: + fibonacci( number-2 )

Remember we are standing in fibonacci(2) so this will do fibonacci(1) and this will return 1.

So now when we return we start going back up so to say, we go out of the function recursively.

What was the problem? when we did fibonacci(4) we needed to know fibonacci(3),fibonacci(2),fibonacci(1) and now we know.

So when it goes out recursively to the fibonacci(3) it will need to know fibonacci(2) and fibonacci(1) and it knows, so now we now fibonacci(3).

Now we go back up to fibonacci(4) for which we need to know fibonacci(3) and fibonacci(2) and we know both so what will it return, the sum of both.

I hope it's clear, recursion is quite hard to follow but it gets better with practice.

Try to follow the function call by call writing down (in pencil) what calls are you calling, and the results you are getting from the calls.

Remember that in this kind of recursion you go down in the levels of recursion "looking for answers" and when you get those answers (returns) you go back up again to give the answers to unknown values.

Comment: Thanks, your post does give me the picture.

Comment: No problem, do ask if you have any question!